Resizing of images for different containers [HTML, CSS, LARAVEL]
There is an issue with the scaling of the image for two different in size containers. The following must be fullfilled
Requirements

Image should look high resolution in two containers (w x h)

Container M size 734 x 417

Container S size 420 x 324




Problems

The image must be created in such a way that it fits the container chosen

If not it doesn't look high resolution


If an image fits one container it automatically doesn't fit another container


Example

Image size 1500 x 880 looks high resolution in the Container M however not that high resolution in the Container S


What i tried

Using different images with different width and height . Want to use only one image file

Using property object-fit: contain  - not entirely fits the criteria



Question

How to resize one image file in a way that it does look high resolution in two different containers ?



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1 id="header"></h1>

    <div>
      <img style="width: 734px; height: 417px; border:1px solid black;" src="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/62c5836076839ad95e36215d/64fb2b64316862df3d2e099a_rcQYosTUaQ6hiJSAk7JphBXJCcZpPSAnq6u8U_3pnj0UVcHM5niGdGNBZ625bnZmRDTg4UQFOjd8tuczIfNSZ7JQeRBtnY4NHvGyGjRBe_DVE4QiDsVy9vcllRT7B1Ut7wx9CBDr945F26Um1hF4xM4.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <div>
      <img style="width: 420px; height: 324px;  border:1px solid black;" src="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/62c5836076839ad95e36215d/64fb2b64316862df3d2e099a_rcQYosTUaQ6hiJSAk7JphBXJCcZpPSAnq6u8U_3pnj0UVcHM5niGdGNBZ625bnZmRDTg4UQFOjd8tuczIfNSZ7JQeRBtnY4NHvGyGjRBe_DVE4QiDsVy9vcllRT7B1Ut7wx9CBDr945F26Um1hF4xM4.png" alt="">
    </div>

    <script src="src/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>




Please visit [ask], then post a [mcve] of your attempt. You can use placeholder.com or loremkitten.com or similar image generators for tests

@mplungjan thank you for the notice. Here is an example of the above described problem

"Doesn't look high resolution" is a bit subjective isn't it? Given your example I don't see what the problem is exactly. The image in both containers looks normal to me aside from the fact that the text is not easily legible, but there's not much you can do about that for a given arbitrary image

would object-fit be what you look for ? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit

Try object-fit: cover;


div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#div1 {
  width: 734px;
  height: 417px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden
}

#div2 {
  width: 420px;
  height: 324px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
<h1 id="header"></h1>

<div id="div1">
  <img src="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/62c5836076839ad95e36215d/64fb2b64316862df3d2e099a_rcQYosTUaQ6hiJSAk7JphBXJCcZpPSAnq6u8U_3pnj0UVcHM5niGdGNBZ625bnZmRDTg4UQFOjd8tuczIfNSZ7JQeRBtnY4NHvGyGjRBe_DVE4QiDsVy9vcllRT7B1Ut7wx9CBDr945F26Um1hF4xM4.png"
    alt="">
</div>

<div id="div2">
  <img src="https://cdn.prod.website-files.com/62c5836076839ad95e36215d/64fb2b64316862df3d2e099a_rcQYosTUaQ6hiJSAk7JphBXJCcZpPSAnq6u8U_3pnj0UVcHM5niGdGNBZ625bnZmRDTg4UQFOjd8tuczIfNSZ7JQeRBtnY4NHvGyGjRBe_DVE4QiDsVy9vcllRT7B1Ut7wx9CBDr945F26Um1hF4xM4.png"
    alt="">
</div>



